# How to map a texture to a distorted quad?

Tags: texturing, uv

First, a picture to show my question:

[image]
As you can see in the second picture, when I scale two vertices of a quad the texture gets distorted wrong. Because a quad is basically two triangles, when I distort the quad only one triangle is being stretched, so the texture warps badly revealing the hidden edge.

I want to map the texture as in the 3rd image (I've done that subdividing the quad multiple times). Is there any option to map the texture so I get the same result?

Comment: can you upload your blend?

Comment: I made this on the fly. Modifying the quad and exporting, and then mix the images in gimp. So I am afraid is not a single blend (and I already deleted it)

Answer (score 4):

If you distort the quad, the UV-map must be distorted the same way to keep the texture undistorted. I suspect you will not like this answer. :)

[image: Undistorted quad]

UV is distorted same as quad.
[image: Distorted quad and distorted UV]

Distort texture in image editor. Or bake from the subdivided mesh to the lowpoly.
[image: Distorted texture]

Comment: I guess it's just how quads work internally, and they are not designed to be distorted.

Answer (score 4):

It is inevitable due to how UV works, because you are making a big distortion on a large area on UV. To solve that, you can add a Subsurf modifier to it, switch to **Simple** mode in the modifier panel, assign a relatively high level (for both View and Render), normally 2 to 4, until you get a expected result.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't only affect the viewport in my case. I tried Cycles and Internal and both get the same issue.

Comment: You are right about it, just updated the answer, thanks!