# Texture distortion on trapeze face

Tags: texturing, uv, subdivision-surface, distort

I have exactly the same problem as it was described there:
[Texture distorted on UV unwrapped face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73173/texture-distorted-on-uv-unwrapped-face)
The texture is distorted (kind of "skewed" or broken) on a trapeze-shaped face.

But the solution provided there does not satisfy me. I need Blender to better interpolate a texture stretched over a single trapeze-shaped face. I can achieve this by subdividing my object, using "simple" method, but I would prefer to avoid that. I want to keep my model low-poly.

Comment: UVs do not interpolate that well, they work best when the geometry is subdivided at regular intervals, making interpolation errors less visible. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188381/help-my-texture-is-distorting/188383#188383

Comment: I see, this is just a very inherent limitation of OpenGL. What's interesting, SketchUp handles this problem perfectly well, even though its viewport rendering is also based on OpenGL. I am curious what is the difference in display between these two programs. SketchUp proves that a solution is possible, yet using some other methods of interpolating.

Comment: Different software will implement different algorithms. **Affine** is used for speed but creates broken projections when triangulating. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping